# retrieve data based on derived column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

How to rewrite the below code as working `sql.` I need to retrieve `'item'` from another table based on my new `'newcol'`

The code is.

```
select 
  s.code,
  o.[work name],
  case when o.[work name] is null 
    then s.code 
    else o.[work name] 
  end newcol,
  item=(select item from table1 where table1.code=newcol)
from 
  shoplog s 
  left outer join odc o on o.barcode=s.code
```

Comment: Is the 'newcol' , is it a column name ? or is it a value?

Comment: value. this is created using case statement. see end of the case statement 'newcol' i need to use this column here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sub-query` to achieve what you need.

```
 select a.code, a.[work name], a.newcol, b.code  as item
  from
  (select
   s.code,
  o.[work name],
  case when o.[work name] is null 
  then s.code 
  else o.[work name] 
  end newcol
  from 
  #shoplog s 
  left outer join #odc o on o.barcode=s.code
  )a
  inner join 
  #table1 b
  on (a.newcol = b.code)
```

Comment: this code is very close what i need but one thing how to group the 'table1' need to select only unique records any idea

Comment: use can use distinct keyword in select query to retrieve the distinct data or you can select distinct data from source table itself like below.   (select distinct code from #table1 ) b